# Creating custom Core Foundation types.

Tags: ios, core-foundation

Is it possible to create custom Core Foundation types?
Does anyone know any document or something that could help me with this?
I'm just trying to port GLKit to iOS 4 to use in a project and there is this GLKMatrixStack type that is a Core Foundation Object.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question, I have two basic answers for you: yes and no.  Heheh.  Regarding your second question (and for further clarification) read on!

It's absolutely possible (and even easy) to do, in the literal sense.  The catch is that it's "private" and therefore against the App Store submission policy.  If you're still interested then to get started I'd refer you both to the comments and to the `EXRange` example in [CFRuntime.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635/CFRuntime.h).  The Core Foundation sources are fairly involved, however, so if you'd like a more detailed explanation or sample code then just let me know.

Comment: Hi ltdowney, is it still possible to work out a custom CF class using just CFBase? Any example is very much appreciated. Thx!